# what are some exotic spaces over which people have defined random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

We usually formulate random variables as functions from some probability space to the space of real numbers $\mathbb R^n$, **i.e. vector-valued random variables**. A more exotic application is a random variable as a function to a function space, such as with Brownian motion, i.e. **function valued random variables**.

**What are some more exotic spaces over which we can define random variables, that have actually been studied and possibly applied in non-trivial ways?**

Comment: Random Matrix Theory is one example (Although $M_{n\times n}$ is homeomorphic and algebraically isomorphic to $\Bbb R^{n^2}$, so this may or may not be “exotic”.

Comment: People in graph theory study random graphs, which are of a fairly different flavor.